# Can't find or open PDB-File C# VS 201 after importing .dll

Tags: c#, dll, pdb-files, dllnotfoundexception

I just imported the MobileDevice.dll (https://mobiledevice.codeplex.com) as Dependency. After importing it this was printed out:

> "ic.vshost.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: ic.vshost.exe): "c:\users\tm\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ic\ic\bin\Debug\MobileDevice.dll" geladen. Can't find or open PDB-File.

I know that it is my DLL which is causing this problem, but I need it in my program so that it works, any Ideas on how I could fix this ?

All other Symbols are loading properly.

Comment: If your program needs PDBs than there is a god chance that one of authors is an expert in debugging/symbol sources and other debugging related internals. Consider asking around in your team in addition to SO... (You probably need better tags on the question - most people don't known  how to deal with using PDB short of copying to correct folder since regular programs never need PDBs)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov thank you.